# No Overload Method "Hit" takes 1 argument. Need to return two Lists

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble called a class function in my main because it needs to return 2 lists at the same time. The function adds a card from one list to another, and then deletes it from the original list. But when I try and call the function I get this error ... No Overload Method "Hit" takes 1 argument

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace BlackJackGameX
    {
        public class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {

                Deck Cards = new Deck();

                Hand PlayerHand = new Hand ();

                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Black Jack\n\nPress Enter To Start");
                Console.ReadLine ();

                PlayerHand.Hit(PlayerHand);
                PlayerHand.Hit(PlayerHand);
                PlayerHand.HandPrint();


            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is at the bottom in the Hit Function of this Hand Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BlackJackGameX
{
    public class Hand
    {

        Deck CardDeck = new Deck ();

        public List<Card> PlayerHand;

        public Hand ()
        {

        }

        public void HandPrint()
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < PlayerHand.Count; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have a " + PlayerHand[i].CardValue + " of " + PlayerHand[i].CardSuit);

                if (i < PlayerHand.Count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("&");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public List<Card> Hit(List<Card> CardDeck, List<Card> PlayerHand)
        {
            PlayerHand.Add(CardDeck[1]);
            CardDeck.Remove(CardDeck[1]);

            return PlayerHand;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to return them? They're references (like pointers), so you don't need to return them, they're already modified.

Comment: To return 2 items one usually uses `Tuple`, but your question is very unclear to really recommend that.

Comment: As you can see I'm way out of my depth, I'm sorry for posting this, I will see if I can work out where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Hit` method is expecting two `List<Card>` parameters, but you're only passing one `Hand` object to it.

```
public List<Card> Hit(List<Card> CardDeck, List<Card> PlayerHand)
{
    ...
}
```

What you need to do is pass the `Cards` object in main to the `Hand` constructor so the Hand can work with it:

```
public class Hand
{
    // You should make this private with a public property to guard it
    public List<Card> PlayerHand;

    // No reason to expose this to the outside
    private Deck cardDeck = new Deck();

    public Hand (Deck cards)
    {
        cardDeck = cards;
    }

    // There's nothing worth returning here, so make it void
    public void Hit()
    {
        // I would probably implement a method in the Deck class
        // so you could do something like (where RemoveNext returns the card removed):
        // playerHand.Add(cards.RemoveNext()); 
        playerHand.Add(CardDeck[1]);
        CardDeck.Remove(CardDeck[1]);
    }
```

And your `Main` looks like this:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Deck cards = new Deck();
    Hand playerHand = new Hand(cards);

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Black Jack\n\nPress Enter To Start");
    Console.ReadLine();

    playerHand.Hit();
    playerHand.Hit();
    // I would rename this to PrintHand(). HandPrint is a noun.
    playerHand.HandPrint();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my code still does work, how would suggest implementing the RemoveNext Function in the deck?

Comment: If your `Deck` class contains a `List` containing whatever you use to represent the cards and the deck is shuffled (randomized) you can just pull from the top of the deck. `var tmp = PlayerHand[0]; PlayerHand.Remove(tmp); return tmp;` should work (or use `RemoveAt(0);`.

Comment: Hi again, I'm sorry but im still struggling to implement the Hit function, I've tried anything I know but it doesn't seem to work, where exactly should I be putting the RemoveAt(0) function? In the Hand class or in the Deck Class?

Comment: Also why am I removing from the PlayerHand, when I want to be taking a card out of the Deck, and adding it to the PlayerHand?

Comment: That was my mistake; you want to remove from the list of cards in the `Deck` object, then return that. Replace `PlayerHand` with the name of that list; the methods are the same.

Comment: I'm sorry I really confused now as to which PlayerHand you mean and what part of my code needs changing, do you think you could show my in code to avoid confusion? I really apologise I just want to get past this obstacle i've been stuck on for days.

Comment: Everything I've mentioned in the comments has been about the `Deck` class concerning a `RemoveNext` (or `DealNext` or whatever you want to call it) method. If your `Deck` class contains a (shuffled) list of cards, you can implement it like `var tmp = myDeckList[0]; myDeckList.Remove(tmp); return tmp;` or `var tmp = myDeckList[0]; myDeckList.RemoveAt(0); return tmp;`. My apologies for the confusion. If you still have trouble then it may be easier to post a new question for it.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help, I will give it a shot, I am determined to figure it out so I actually learn something!

Comment: Ok so I made the Hit function in my Deck Class, but I can't seem to add the return value to my player Hand?

Comment: Try something like `playerHand.Add(cards.RemoveNext());` in your `Hit` method. `RemoveNext` returns the card (that was the `return tmp;` line), then `Add` takes that card, creates a new spot at the end of the list, and places the card into that spot.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're having is because the `Hit()` Method in your `Hand` class accepts 2 paramaters, not 1.  It's expecting two `List<Card>()` paramaters.

Your code is passing in a `Hand` object which won't work at all, regardless of the number of paramaters.

Comment: Then how do I utilize my lists from my other classes in the main function?

Comment: @JonDunn I see no lists in the main function, only Hand and Deck objects.

Comment: The Deck class is a list of shuffled cards, the Hand class is ment to contain a List of the player's cards